# How to change URL on render in Django?

Tags: django, url, redirect

When I was searching about it in google, i found only answers that didn't help actually help me. My problem is really simple: I just want to change URL in browser, when I render. (When i was searching i found that i can't pass any data to redirect() function so it isn't the good way).

"post" method triggers when user submit form (there will be some validation etc. but at the end of the day I'll need to render template (home if user wrote credentials correctly or login again to show user if he wrote credentials incorrectly)). When I render some template, URL in browser will be "/submit_login" instead of "/login".

Here's this part of code:

in urls.py

```
path('login/', login.as_view(), name='login'),
path('submit_login/', login.as_view(), name='submit_login'),
```

in views.py

```
class login(View):

template_src = "login.html"

# showing user login view
def get(self, request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, self.template_src, { 'form': form })

#This triggers when user submit form 
def post(self, request):

    #I tried request.path_info but it didn't work also
    #request.path_info = "/login/"
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
    #When I call this URL is still "/submit_login" instead of "/login"
    return render(request, self.template_src, {'form': form })
```

template (if someone wants to see what I am trying to do):

```
{% extends 'base_template.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1> here you can login to your account! </h1>
<form name = "form" action="{% url 'submit_login' %}"method="post"> 
   {% csrf_token %}

   {{form}}
   <input type = "submit" value = "login!"/>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Have you got any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Why use a different url in the firsst place? Simply use `action="{% url 'login' %}"` here.

Comment: Yes, I found it on my own. It worked for this example. But for more advanced apps? Is there any solution?